# Print scope in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

So I create a class in Swift (Xcode 7, Swift 2.1) in a project,

```
import Foundation

class Banana {

    init(){
    }

    func print()  -> String {
        print( "yo mama here" )
        return "yo mama"
    }

}
```

The print call is creating an in-IDE error **Argument passed to call that takes no arguments**

It feels like a scope problem, but I can't be sure. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: just rename the print() funtion to something else . For example display()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `func print()` is conflicting with the Swift standard library function `func print(Any...)`. I would recommend not using `print` as a function name, but if you really need to do this, you can call the Swift version using `Swift.print("stuff")`.